# How to build a game with Adobe's RTMFP?

Tags: adobe, rtmfp, adobe-cirrus

I want to develop a simple car race game, where certain number of players connect to a lobby and play the game at the same time. A game like [haxball](http://haxball.com).

I read that RTMFP is a good choice for that. I know ActionScript 3, so where should I start to build such a game?

I found **Cirrus**, but in this article, it says :

> In order to use RTMFP, Flash Player endpoints must connect to an
>   RTMFP-capable server, such as the Codename Cirrus (previously Codename
>   Stratus) service or Flash Media Server 4. Cirrus is a hosted
>   rendezvous service that aids establishing communications between Flash
>   Player endpoints. Unlike FMS, Cirrus does not support media relay,
>   shared objects, scripting, etc. So by using Cirrus, you can develop
>   applications only where Flash Player endpoints are directly
>   communicating with one another.

So is cirrus suitable for my need?

And so, where should I start to code? Maybe an example game?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cirrus is deprecated by Adobe.

You can use either Flash Media Server for Amazon AWS.

Or hosting services like Influxis.

Comment: @Alexander Farber, Cirrus ain't deprecated yet. Can you suggest any link for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Citrus is fine for what you need. I created a game similar to haxball but connected the players directly to reduce lag in a real P2P mesh. At haxball, each client connects to a server and the latency is higher and if the host decides to leave = Game Over

Check out [Bilu Ball](http://www.bilub.com) you can see the game in action and the low latency gameplay.

Also check for some P2P libraries which will handle all the communication between client, I used this one: http://code.google.com/p/as3mul/

Also read about how to reduce lag and techniques how to decrease the size of the messages between clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can very well go with Adobe Cirrus for your application.

However, it's a free p2p service and there are certain limitations for using their service. If your application makes use of more than 10000 concurrent connections to cirrus, then you need to get a consent from Adobe.

Currently, the cirrus service is being abused by some people it may be down at present. But *Cirrus is not officially deprecated*